# Prevent overwriting Database when updating ClickOnce Application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sqlite, clickonce

I finished my c# Click once application, so I published it.
The problem with it is, that I'am using a small SQLite database, for keeping settings and a lot of other small things, which will get overwritten by the new SQLite database, every time I update my application.

There are settings in the database like: Remember password and Remember username, there is also a counter, that counts how many times the application has been started. All of that will be lost and the user will have to fill in his username and password again, even if he checked the boxes to remember, because the database will be overwritten.

**Question:** How do I prevent to SQLite Database from getting overwritten in my Click Once application?

Comment: Clickonce upgrades the application in the client machine, and how does it update the database? Where is this database server located?

Comment: The database is located in the project folder, it isn't on a server, because it doesn't need to. So I update the database from visual studio in my project and then press publish.

Comment: This can be helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3597296/updating-local-sql-server-databases-with-clickonce-deployment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the following link to solve my problem:

http://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2009/08/19/where-do-i-put-my-data-to-keep-it-safe-from-clickonce-updates/

This article explains how I can create my Database in the roaming folder of AppData, create a folder there called like your company name or the name of your application and put the Database in that folder.

Answer (score 0):

You should have "Template" database which will always override and created database with data which will not override after installing of new version of application.

The database with data should be created if it doesn't exist at startup of application.

Comment: The database gets created when it doesn't exist, because the application will check if it exists yes or no, but if there is a database, it will be deleted because Clickonce deletes everything and puts the new publish in place.

Comment: Typically, installation folder should be static (even if it's AppData). You can use subfolder of MyDocuments or AppData as placeholder for DB.